# Getting network info in Java on Windows and Linux platforms

Tags: java, windows, linux, network-programming

I need Network configuration information in my application that is more than what `java.net.NetworkInterface` and `java.net.InetAddress` provide.  I would like to include information such as Subnet, Gateway, and DNS servers, but code needs to be portable to both Windows and Linux platforms.

I have looked into doing it by doing `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ipconfig")` for Windows and `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ifconfig")` for Linux and parsing the results.  Maybe there is a better way to do this or an open source project that I could use.

Thanks in advance for any ideas that can steer me in the right direction

Comment: invoking ifconfig and ipconfig break the use of portability.  Could you post what code you currently have?

Comment: I made a factory method to call into the separate implementations for each OS.  For windows, I am calling 'ipconfig /all' and parsing the results.  For linux, I am calling 'ifconfig', 'route -n', and 'cat /etc/resolv.conf'.

Comment: Also, default installs of some linux distributions do not include /sbin in the path, so calling that might fail depending on the user

Comment: Thanks Rob, good to know.  There is only one user that the application runs under and the user has the correct permissions. Also, the only linux dist I need to it work for is Ubuntu.  This isn't the ideal way I would have liked to write the code, but at least I have it extendable for other implementations if need be.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking of a better and more robust solution,you could probably use the idea of SNMP(Simple Network Management Protocol).There are several API's available for use,SNMP4J being the most famous and open source.Since SNMP is supported across multiple Operating Systems and even switches and routers,it is probably a good idea to use it of you want in depth network level statistics.But if you want a more simple solution then use the Sigar API,which supports many OS including windows and linux.One problem with Sigar is that it is licensed under GPL which prohibits you to deploy it in a commercial project.

Comment: SNMP is nice as long as the user of the software does not have to install and configure it.. SIGAR looks good and is definitely easier to work with than having to deal with highly OS-specific low level APIs. Eg. the Linux netlink api can provide most of the information, but is quite horrible.

Comment: @Madhu Sudhan Sigar package have Apache 2.0 license inside. Do you sure about GPL?

Comment: I am not sure about the licensing,but I think it cannot be deployed in a commercial project.Just drop a mail to the sigar sales team about the licensing.I am sure that they can help you better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could do in native code, and use JNI.
Then ship a .dll for windows, and an .so (or source code) for linux,
though this probably isn't a whole lot better than the 'exec' solution.